# Call a PHP file from Javascript (AJAX?)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, html

## The Problem:

Hello, I have researched AJAX online and i don't really understand it. I am trying to call a php file from within a javascript function and unfortunately it is not working. I am trying everything but i still do not get it. Hopefully people here can explain it to me with my code as an example.

---

## Javascript:

***Here is the function I want to call the file from:***

```
function countdownEnded() {
    //make serverscreen dissapear
        document.getElementById('serverScreenWrapper').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('serverScreenWrapper').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById("cashOutNumTwo").style.right = '150%';
        document.getElementById("cashOutNumOne").style.right = '150%';
//start Timer
        setInterval(gameTimer.update, 1000);
//make player move again
        socket.emit('4');
        socket.emit('6');
//make game appear
        document.getElementById('gameAreaWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
//play sound
        document.getElementById('spawn_cell').play();
//cut 5 cents from account - php function
        //CALL PHP FUNCTION HERE WITH AJAX
}
```

So the php file is basically | ../../../../subtract5.php | in relation to the other file.

---

## PHP:

Here is the file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPass";
$dbname = "myDBname";
$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

// You must enter the user's id here. /\

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid
$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 0.05;
$newAmount = $cash_amount - 0.05;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = $newAmount WHERE id = $userid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
   echo "5 cents have been subtracted!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
   session_start();
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

## Conclusion:

How can i call this file from the function, and as a bonus: if i wanted to send a javascript variable over to the file to be used to update my database, how can i do that?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Write this part of code your javascript function

```
function countdownEnded() {
       /* Your Code */
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/subtract5.php',
        data: { },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So even though the file is a couple folders back, i don't have to write the relation? (../../../)

Comment: yes. you have to specify the exact location of the file.

Comment: if the file is stored in **html-root/your-project/folder1/folder2/** , url is like **~/folder1/folder2/subtract5.php**

Comment: Alright i tested it and the database did not update at all. Do you know why?

Comment: @Patrick did you include the needed script files for AJAX HTTP calls to work?

Comment: The php file must be accessible by the browser. Try setting the absolute path, like https://example.com/whatever/yourfile.php. If the file isn't within the server document root you can't perform an Ajax request.

Comment: So i tested it and it still is not working, but now it says this for the php file: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: @ivanivan i have jquery as a src on the html file, is that what you are referring to?